# Is there a Graphics primitive for a cone without a base?

Tags: graphics3d

Is there an easy way to get a graphics primitive for a cone without a base without using `RevolutionPlot3D`?  I'm trying to create an "manipulable" animation of the "space" and "body" cones for a body rotating in three dimensions (like the two animations at the bottom of the page [here](http://www.aero.iitb.ac.in/~bhat/axisymmetric.html), but with adjustable parameters.)  I've already created an animation like that using `Cone` objects, but their circular faces are always drawn, and I can't figure out how to tell *Mathematica* not to do that.  (I'd rather not resort to revolution plots since this would require a massive overhaul of my code.)

In case you're curious:  the code I have right now is a bit of a mess (in particular, it uses all sorts of special characters and subscripts, and so doesn't cut-and-paste well), but I can try to post it upon request.

Comment: I want this too, +1. I was looking for this not too long ago and came up empty-handed.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
openCone[{{x1_, y1_, z1_}, {x2_, y2_, z2_}}, r_] := 
 {CapForm[None], Tube[{{x1, y1, z1}, {x2, y2, z2}}, {r, 0}]}

Graphics3D[openCone[{{0, 0, 1}, {1, 1, 0}}, 1]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 9):

I like Rahul's approach the most. An alternative way to produce open cones is to treat the cone as a NURBS surface:

```
openCone[{p1_?VectorQ, p2_?VectorQ}, r_?NumericQ] :=
    With[{tr = Composition[TranslationTransform[p1],
                           RotationTransform[{{0, 0, 1}, p2 - p1}]]}, 
         BSplineSurface[{tr /@ PadRight[r {{1, 0}, {1, 1}, {-1, 1}, {-1, 0},
                                           {-1, -1}, {1, -1}, {1, 0}},
                                        {Automatic, 3}], ConstantArray[p2, 7]}, 
                        SplineClosed -> {False, True}, SplineDegree -> {1, 2}, 
                        SplineKnots -> {{0, 0, 1, 1},
                                        {0, 0, 0, 1/4, 1/2, 1/2, 3/4, 1, 1, 1}},
                        SplineWeights ->
                        ConstantArray[{1, 1/2, 1/2, 1, 1/2, 1/2, 1}, 2]]]

With[{p1 = {0, 0, 1}, p2 = {1, 1, 0}, r = 1},
     {Graphics3D[openCone[{p1, p2}, r], Boxed -> False], 
      Graphics3D[Cone[{p1, p2}, r], Boxed -> False]} // GraphicsRow]
```

[image: open and closed cones]

Answer (score 4):

```
Graphics3D[Cone[],
 ClipPlanes -> {{0, 0, 1, 1}},
 Axes -> True]
```

[image]

Comment: It may happen that there will be something more in `Graphics3d` :)

Answer (score 3):

Just in case of `Tube` not being around. You won't have to change anything if you define syntax for your `cone` the same way the built in one is.

```
cone[{p1_, p2_}, r_] := GeometricTransformation[
  First @ RevolutionPlot3D[(-x/r + 1) Norm[p2 - p1], {x, 0, r}, 
            Mesh -> None, PerformanceGoal -> "Speed", PlotPoints -> 20],
  { RotationMatrix[{{0, 0, 1}, p2 - p1}], p1}
]


p1 = {1, 2, 1}
p2 = {2, 3, 2}
r = .2
Graphics3D[{
  cone[{p1, p2}, r]
  ,
  Translate[Cone[{p1, p2}, r], {1, 1, 1}]
  },
 BoxRatios -> Automatic]
```

> [image]

ref: [Change position and orientation of 3D object](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/100026/5478)