# Get Graphics3D object for only part of a cone

Tags: graphics3d, regions

I have the necessary information to define a cone and plot it in Mathematica:

```
Rc = 0.38663124715321806`;
cvec = {0.9549268454424656`, 
   0.693794964347954`, -0.18315267078439607`};

openCone[{{x1_, y1_, z1_}, {x2_, y2_, z2_}}, r_] := {CapForm[None], 
  Tube[{{x1, y1, z1}, {x2, y2, z2}}, {r, 0}]}

cone = Graphics3D[{openCone[{cvec, {0, 0, 0}}, Rc]}];
```

where I have used the `openCone[]` defined here: [Is there a Graphics primitive for a cone without a base?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/101575/is-there-a-graphics-primitive-for-a-cone-without-a-base)

This is all good. Now I would like to go one step further. I have the locations of two vectors lying on the cone:

```
tvec1={1.15282, 0.490827, 0.0797662};
tvec2={0.823045, 0.944722, 0.0797662};
```

Plotting everything together,

```
Show[cone,
 Graphics3D[{Thick, Blue, Line[{{0, 0, 0}, tvec1}], 
   Line[{{0, 0, 0}, tvec2}], 
   {Red, Point[cvec]}}]
 ]
```

I get the picture:

[image]

Now, what I want to do is plot only the section of the cone that lies between the two blue lines (make a `Graphics3D` object)-- let's say the smaller section. How would I do that?

The simplest theoretical approach that I can think of is to define the plane comprised of `tvec1`, `tvec2` and `{0,0,0}`, and plot only the 'points' that lie above (or below) the plane. But I have no idea how to implement this, especially since all I have is a `Graphics3D` object. Please help.

---

ADDENDUM: Why I am asking for a new `Graphics3D` object ...

I want more than just to display part of the cone (hence, an option like `ClipPlanes` doesn't suffice). I want a new `Graphics3D` object so that I can do other operations with it.

In particular, I have a collection of many of these cones and other `Graphics3D` objects pieced together, and I want to apply the smoothing procedures `GraphDiffusionFlow[]` and `MeanCurvatureFlow[]` to the whole complex (defined here: [Smoothing 3D contours as post processing](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/172517/smoothing-3d-contours-as-post-processing)).

My understanding is that I need a meshed surface for applying these functions, hence my request for a `Graphics3D` object so that I can use something like `DiscretizeGraphics[]`. As mentioned in a comment, the current definition of `openCone` doesn't support `DiscretizeGraphics[]` since contains a `Tube`. So I need an alternative.

Comment: "section of the cone that lies between the two blue lines" - the larger one or the smaller one?

Comment: Either. Fine, let's say the smaller one to be precise. I will modify the question accordingly.

Comment: Why not just plot the piece you need via ParametricPlot3D[{h Cos[t], h Sin[t],h},{t,a,b},{h,c,d}]?

Comment: @Dominic How would I create a `Graphics3D` object out of that, that I could, say, use `DiscretizeGraphics[]` on?

Comment: Not sure why you want to discretize it but you could extract the point data (points,index) from the GraphicsComplex and then manually discretize it:  pp = ParametricPlot3D[{h Cos[t], h Sin[t], h}, {t, 0, Pi/2}, {h, 0, 2}];
myPlotData = Cases[pp, GraphicsComplex[x1___] :> x1, Infinity];
DiscretizeGraphics[Graphics3D@GraphicsComplex[myPlotData[[1]], myPlotData[[2]]]]

Comment: You cannot use `DiscretizeGraphics/BoundaryDiscretizeGraphics` on `openCone` (or any primitives created  using `Tube`s)  because (unlike `Cone`, Cylinder`, `Cuboid` etc.) `Tube` is not a _region_ primitive.

Comment: @Dominic I have modified my post to show why exactly I want to discretise the mesh. Can Daniel Huber's `openCone[]` below be treated in the way you described?

Comment: Since you wanted a region, I was going to suggest something like `RegionIntersection[Cone[{cvec, {0, 0, 0}}, Rc], HalfSpace[Cross[tvec2, tvec1], {0, 0, 0}]]`, but the results seem to be mixed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We construct a space circle by

```
 cvec + Rc*(Cos[t]*e1 + Sin[t]*e2)
```

and then extrude the point `o={0,0,0}` to this circle to construct the cone.

```
s*o + (1 - s)*(cvec + Rc*(Cos[t]*e1 + Sin[t]*e2))
```

At the end, we use the two lines `tvec1` and `tvec2` to define a half space to separated the two part of cone.

```
HalfSpace[sign*Cross[tvec1 - o, tvec2 - o], o]
```

```
Rc = 0.38663124715321806`;
cvec = {0.9549268454424656`, 
   0.693794964347954`, -0.18315267078439607`};
tvec1 = {1.15282, 0.490827, 0.0797662};
tvec2 = {0.823045, 0.944722, 0.0797662};
o = {0, 0, 0};
{v1, v2, v3} = # & /@ HodgeDual[cvec - o];
e1 = Normalize[v1];
e3 = Normalize[cvec - o];
e2 = Cross[e1, e3];
Table[ParametricPlot3D[
  s*o + (1 - s)*(cvec + Rc*(Cos[t]*e1 + Sin[t]*e2)), {t, 0, 
   2 π}, {s, 0, 1}, Boxed -> False, Axes -> False, Mesh -> None, 
  RegionFunction -> 
   Function[{x, y, z}, 
    RegionMember[
     HalfSpace[sign*Cross[tvec1 - o, tvec2 - o], o], {x, y, 
      z}]]], {sign, {1, -1}}]
```

[image]

Comment: Brilliant! What exactly is the `HodgeDual[]` function and what does it do here? I had never heard of it.

Comment: @ap21  I use HodgeDual to create some vectors to  perpendicular to `cvec - o`,maybe we can find another function to do this.

Comment: That's fine, it works perfectly well.

Answer (score 1):

We may draw a piece of a cone using `ParametricPlot3D`. Toward this end, we redefine the function `openCone`.

We need following data: the point at the base: `pbase` and at the tip: `ptip` of the cone. Then we need two points: `pts` on the base circle, defining the start and the end of the cone section. Finally we need the radius: `r` of the base.

For the cone section we define a function `cir[phi_]` that returns the point on the base circles that, together with the center, defines a line that makes an angle of `phi` with line from the base center in x direction.. We further define `angle[v1_v2_]` that returns the angle between 2 3D vectors. With the help of these 2 function we can create a plot of the cone section.

```
openCone[{p1_, p0_}, {p2_, p3_}, r_] := 
  Module[{cir, ph2, ph3, n = Normalize[p0 - p1], t, q0, qx, qy, qz}, 
   cir[ph_] := p1 + r  RotationMatrix[ph, n].q0;
   angle[v1_, v2_] := (t = ArcTan[v1.v2, Cross[v1, v2].n]; 
     If[t < 0, 2 Pi + t, t]);
   {qx, qy, qz} = pbase - ptip;
   q0 = If[qx == qy == 0, {1, 0, 0}, {-qy, qx, 0}/Sqrt[qx^2 + qy^2]];
   ph2 = angle[q0, p2 - p1];
   ph3 = angle[q0, p3 - p1];
   
   ParametricPlot3D[p0 + l (cir[ph] - p0), {l, 0, 1}, {ph, ph2, ph3}, 
    BoxRatios -> Automatic]];
```

Here is an example:

```
pbase = {1, 0, 0}; ptip = {1., 1, 1}; r = 1;
{qx, qy, qz} = pbase - ptip;
q0 = If[qx == qy == 0, {r, 0, 0}, r {-qy, qx, 0}/Sqrt[qx^2 + qy^2]];
pts = ({pbase +  RotationMatrix[p1, ptip - pbase].q0, 
     pbase + RotationMatrix[p2, ptip - pbase].q0} /. {p1 -> 0, 
     p2 -> Pi 5/4});
Show[t = openCone[{pbase, ptip}, pts, r], 
 Graphics3D[{Blue, Thickness[0.01], 
   Line[{{ptip, pts[[1]]}, {ptip, pts[[2]]}}], PointSize[0.02], 
   Point[pts]}], Axes -> True, AxesLabel -> {"x", "y", "z"}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! Does your `openCone` qualify for the functions that I have mentioned in my addendum about what I want to do with these cones?

Comment: I am sorry, but if I try your function with the parameters `cvec`, `Rc`, `tvec1` and `tvec2` defined in my post, then I don't get the correct cone. Could you please look into it? The tip is at `{0,0,0}`.

Comment: The calculation of `pts` was only for the example and not general. I changed this. I also generalized `openCone`. Fpr your example you waould specify `pbase = cvec; ptip = {0, 0, 0}; r = Rc;`. However, the calculation of `pts` seems a bit cumbersome.  Would it be easier to specify the start and end point of the cone section by angles?

Comment: `openCone` returns a G`raphics3D` object same as e.g.  `Plot3D `,`ListPlot3D` e.t.c. Therefore it should be compatible.